# Assigning CSV values to structure

Tags: data-structures, basic

I'm creating what should be a simple program but I'm having some difficulty assigning values from a file into a structure and it's variables. Visual Basic.

Structure:

```
Public Structure Teams
Dim teamName As String    
End Structure
```

Function:

```
    Function getAvailableTeams() As Teams()
    Dim rec As Teams
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim recCount As Integer = 0

    'Count how many teams exist
    FileOpen(1, "teamConfig.csv", OpenMode.Input)
    Do Until EOF(1)
        LineInput(1) 'Read document line by line
        recCount += 1 'Increment team count by 1
    Loop

    'store team names in array
    Dim teamNames(recCount - 1) As Teams
    index = 0
    Do Until EOF (1)
        Input(1, rec.teamName)

        teamNames(index).teamName = rec.teamName

        index +=1
    Loop
    FileClose(1)

    Return teamNames
End Function
```

Simple subroutine to test values are available and being picked up.

```
   Dim availableTeams() As Teams
    availableTeams = getAvailableTeams()
   lbltest.text = availableTeams(1).toString
```

The file is stored as a CSV file and there are 11 available team names. 
   team1 \r\n
   team2 \r\n
   etc...

I appreciate this is probably something simple but I can't work out where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: What are you actually seeing as the return value from getAvailableTeams() ?

Comment: projectName.modStrucs+Teams   , this is is the case for all 11 records.

Comment: I'm not up on old VB stuff, but I notice that in one loop you use `LineInput` and in the other you use `Input`. Are you sure there's no difference between the two?

Comment: I suspect you need to seek to the beginning of the file again after your first loop i.e. place Seek(0) after the loop that determines how many record you have.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments was on the right track.  You need to close and re-open the file for input to start at the beginning again.  Since you were already at end-of-file, the second attempt fails immediately unless you re-start from the beginning.